# PL/SQL exceptions dont raise

Tags: exception, plsql

I'm new to PL/SQL and I've been struggling with this problem waay too long so I thought I'll ask here:

**What I want to achieve:**

- I want to insert a new employee into my 'emp' table using pl/sql
  blocks.
- I want the data to be input from the keyboard.
- Then check if the data is correct using exceptions.
- After that I want the user to confirm it writing 'yes' or 'no'.

**What doesn't work:**

- Exceptions are not being raised even though I input invalid data.
- As it is now it asks the user to confirm at the same time as asking for the data. I want it to ask after inputing and after checking the
  correctness

**My code:**

```
DECLARE
  empno   NUMBER;
  ename   Varchar2(30);
  job     Varchar2(30);
  mgr     NUMBER;
  hiredate DATE;
  sal     NUMBER;
  comm    NUMBER;
  deptno  NUMBER;
  confirm VARCHAR2(3);
  negative_number EXCEPTION;
  invalid_date    EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO emp
  VALUES (&empno, '&ename', '&job', &mgr, '&hiredate', &sal, &comm, &deptno);
  IF empno < 0 OR mgr < 0 OR sal < 0 OR comm < 0 OR deptno < 0 THEN
    RAISE negative_number;
  ELSIF hiredate > SYSDATE THEN
    RAISE invalid_date;
  END IF;
  IF '&confirm' = 'yes' THEN commit;
  ELSE rollback;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN negative_number THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('number cannot be negative');
  WHEN invalid_date THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('cannot be future date');
END;
```

Comment: You are swalling the exceptions in your `exception` block. If you want them to be raised to the caller, you need to re-raise them

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what does swalling mean? how do I re-raise them?

Comment: Sorry I meant "swallow". For details on raising exceptions please see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#BABFHFBI

Comment: I don't understand, I'm doing it exactly as it says: 1. declare 2.raise 3. handle

Comment: But you are catching the exceptions in the `exception` block. And as the `exception` block doesn't do anything besides printing a message the exception is effectively swallowed. Either remove the `exception` block or re-`raise` the exceptions there if you need the error messages

Comment: but I just want it to print the message. And it doesn't do that.

Comment: What are you running this from - sqlplus? Did you set serveroutput on ?

Comment: Assuming you're running this PL/SQL on the server, it's not well designed for interactive programs - you can't ask for user input halfway through the procedure.

Comment: This is not a requirement suitable for implementation in PL/SQL, as it's not interactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little modification to your present code:

```
DECLARE
  empno   NUMBER := &empno;
  ename   Varchar2(30) := '&ename';
  job     Varchar2(30) := '&job';
  mgr     NUMBER := &mgr;
  hiredate DATE := TO_DATE('&hiredate', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
  sal     NUMBER := &sal;
  comm    NUMBER := &comm;
  deptno  NUMBER := &deptno;
  confirm VARCHAR2(3);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO emp
  VALUES (empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno);
  IF empno < 0 OR mgr < 0 OR sal < 0 OR comm < 0 OR deptno < 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ('-20001', 'Number cannot be negative!');
  ELSIF hiredate > SYSDATE THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ('-20002', 'Cannot be future date!');
  END IF;
  confirm := '&confirm';
  IF lower(confirm) IN ('yes', 'y') THEN
    commit;
  ELSE
    rollback;
  END IF;
END;
```

The last part - `confirm` is not possible using pure PL/SQL though. What the code does is get the value of `confirm` at the beginning of the execution itself, along with other variables. What you should do for this is build a front-end that would control the flow of your program before issuing a DML.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE

  empno   NUMBER := 10;
  ename   Varchar2(30) := 'sinha';
  job     Varchar2(30) := 'ITTTT';
  mgr     NUMBER := 100;
  hiredate DATE := TO_DATE('09/09/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
  sal     NUMBER := 2000;
  comm    NUMBER := 50;
  deptno  NUMBER := 10;
  invalid_emp exception;
  invalid_date exception;

BEGIN

  INSERT INTO empl
  VALUES (empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno);

  IF empno < 0 OR mgr < 0 OR sal < 0 OR comm < 0 OR deptno < 0 THEN
    RAISE invalid_emp;
  ELSIF hiredate > SYSDATE THEN
    RAISE invalid_date;
  END IF;

  exception
  when invalid_emp then
  dbms_output.put_line('number cannot be negative');
  when invalid_date then 
  dbms_output.put_line('cannot be future date');
END;
```

this is how you can use a user defined exception as you wanted

Comment: You are eating all the exceptions again.

Comment: Sorry but if you have defined exception for this then even if you put confirm as 'Y' it will be cached by exception and will not get committed so i have not used confirm.

Comment: In your `exception` block, all you are doing after raising `invalid_emp` and `invalid_date` is that you are displaying just an error message. You are not stopping the program from proceeding with the `INSERT`. Just use `RAISE;` in your exception blocks.

Comment: what you are using is pragma exception init and even with this behaviour remains the same i am not stoping any dml to be executed.moreover if you want the commit and rollback statement in the block after "sucessful" DML then you can use the confirm part.The question was about to use userdefined exception so i have used it.